# How to send these values to mail with database

Tags: php

I am new in php. Not able to send these values to mail. I want to send this form value to mail and my database both. And is 2 mail possible? I use this form as popup on my website all right in form code it is sending values to database.

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = '********';
$password = '*****';
$dbname = '********';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['mailsend']))
{
    $firstname  = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $number     = $_POST['number'];
    $query      = $_POST['query'];
    $subject = "A New Query";
    $message = "Name:" .$firstname. "\r\n";
    $message .=" Email:" .$email.  "\r\n" ; 
    $message .= "Mobile Number:" .$number. "\r\n"; 
    $message .= "Query:" .$query. "\r\n"; 
    print_r($message);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO query (name,email,phone,query) VALUES ('$firstname', '$email', '$number', '$query')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Message Sent Sucessfully, We will contact you soon.');</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Certainly that is possible, but your code does not show any attempt to send an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your php. that will work for you enter your mail id there and you can two email id there put your both email.

```
 <?php

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = '********';
$password = '*****';
$dbname = '********';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error){
    trigger_error("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



if (isset($_REQUEST['mailsend'])){
    $firstname  = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $number     = $_POST['number'];
    $query      = $_POST['query'];


    $to = "enter_your@email.com";  //enter your mail id here
    $tosec = "second_email@here.com";  //enter your second mail id here



  $subject = "A New Query";

 $message = "Name:" .$firstname. "\r\n";
 $message .=" Email:" .$email.  "\r\n" ; 
 $message .= "Mobile Number:" .$number. "\r\n"; 
 $message .= "Query:" .$query. "\r\n"; 


 //print_r($message);

    $return = mail($to,$subject,$message);
    $returnsec = mail($tosec,$subject,$message);        


if($retrun && $returnsec){  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO query SET 
      `name` = '{$firstname}',
      `email` = '{$email}',
      `phone` = '{$number}',
      `query` = '{$query}'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "<script>alert('Your Message Sent Sucessfully, We will contact you soon.');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
  }
 } ?>
```

Comment: This _might_ work... It relies on php's email gateway setup correctly configured. In most cases it is better to use a smtp client from within php.